# how to calculate value using previous other columns' value in python

Tags: python, row

I'd like to calculate rate of return from Dataframe belows.
Using other columns' previous row, even group by `id`
To be specific ,

From

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['Blue', 'Blue','Blue','Red','Red'],
                            'a':[100,200,300,1,2], 
                            'b':[10,20,15,3,2],
                            'c':[1,2,3,4,5]})
>>> df
     id    a   b  c
0  Blue  100  10  1
1  Blue  200  20  2
2  Blue  300  15  3
3   Red    1   3  4
4   Red    2   2  5
```

I want to make following.

`df['new_col'] = a / a(previous row value) + b(previous row value) - c(previous row value)`

I think `pct_change()` doen't help since it works only same column.

```
>>> df
     id    a   b  c   new_col
0  Blue  100  10  1   -
1  Blue  200  20  2   = 200 / (100 + 10 - 1)
2  Blue  300  15  3   = 300 / (200 + 20 - 2)
3   Red    1   3  4   -
4   Red    2   2  5   = 2 / (1 + 3 - 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
def fn(g):
    out = g['a'] / (g['a'].shift() + g['b'].shift() - g['c'].shift())
    g['new_col'] = out
    return g

df = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     id    a   b  c   new_col
0  Blue  100  10  1       NaN
1  Blue  200  20  2  1.834862
2  Blue  300  15  3  1.376147
3   Red    1   3  4       NaN
4   Red    2   2  5       inf
```